# Performances on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem of performances with rails. When i do an ajax call to a controller like this :

```
def test
    @hotels = Hotel.all
    render :json => ['hotels' => @hotels ], :include=> [:country, :city]
end
```

It takes maybe 2-5 seconds to finish. I only have 40 hotels in my database. I think it very long... for example, the same request on Django will take 400ms

Did i forgot to configure well my environement?

I use Rails entreprise version and passenger.

EDIT : My log file :

```
     Started GET "/hotels/test.json" for 172.16.81.1 at Wed Oct 12 22:11:06 +0200 2011
    [paperclip] Duplicate URL for image with /system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename. This will clash with attachment defined in HotelImage class
    [paperclip] Duplicate URL for thumbnail with /system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename. This will clash with attachment defined in Hotel class
    [paperclip] Duplicate URL for map with /system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename. This will clash with attachment defined in Hotel class
    [paperclip] Duplicate URL for thumbnail with /system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename. This will clash with attachment defined in DestinationAlbumPhoto class
    [paperclip] Duplicate URL for map with /system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename. This will clash with attachment defined in Destination class
    [paperclip] Duplicate URL for image with /system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename. This will clash with attachment defined in Continent class
    [paperclip] Duplicate URL for thumbnail with /system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename. This will clash with attachment defined in Destination class
    [paperclip] Duplicate URL for image with /system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename. This will clash with attachment defined in Event class
    [paperclip] Duplicate URL for thumbnail with /system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename. This will clash with attachment defined in HotelAlbumPhoto class
    [paperclip] Duplicate URL for map with /system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename. This will clash with attachment defined in Event class
      Processing by HotelController#test as JSON
      [1m[36mHotel Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `hotels`.* FROM `hotels`[0m
      [1m[35mCountry Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT `countries`.* FROM `countries` WHERE (`countries`.`id` = 3)
      [1m[36mCity Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `cities`.* FROM `cities` WHERE (`cities`.`id` = 2)[0m
    Completed 200 OK in 405ms (Views: 366.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

It's writen 405ms but firefox tell me 3,7sec.

My hotel model :

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  cattr_reader :per_page
  @@per_page = 16

  belongs_to :hotel_type
  belongs_to :hotel_theme
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :destination
  belongs_to :continent

  has_many :hotel_comments, :dependent => :destroy

  has_many :hotel_album_photos, :dependent => :destroy

  has_many :hotel_activity_values

  has_many :hotel_service_values

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :hotel_album_photos

  has_attached_file :thumbnail, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "191x134>"} , :default_url => '/images/default/missing.png' 
  has_attached_file :map, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "191x134>"} , :default_url => '/images/default/missing.png' 

  scope :country, lambda { |country_id|
     self.scoped.where('country_id IN ( ? )', country_id) unless country_id.blank?
  }

  scope :selection, lambda { |selection|
     self.scoped.where('selection = ? ', 1) unless selection.blank?
  }

  scope :city, lambda { |city_id|
      self.scoped.where('city_id IN ( ? )', city_id) unless city_id.blank?
  }

  scope :hoteltype, lambda { |type|
      self.scoped.where('hotel_type_id IN ( ? )', type) unless type.blank?
   }

  scope :theme, lambda { |theme|
      self.scoped.where('hotel_theme_id IN ( ? )', theme) unless theme.blank?
   }

  scope :prices, lambda { |prices|
      condition = []
      prices.each do |price|
        pricesArray = price.split('-')
        condition.push '(price BETWEEN ' + pricesArray[0] + ' AND ' + pricesArray[1] + ')'
      end
      self.scoped.where(condition.join(' OR ')) 
   }

   scope :order_by_price, lambda { |direction|
     self.scoped.order('price ' + direction)
   }

   scope :order_by_rate, lambda { |rate|
     self.scoped.order('global_rate ' + rate)
   }

   scope :services, lambda { |services|
      {:joins => [:hotel_service_values ]  , :conditions => { :hotel_service_values => {:hotel_service_id  => services}}}
   }

  scope :limiter, lambda { |limiter|
      self.scoped.limit(limiter)
   }

end
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Can you see what the console output or log file is telling you? How much time is spent in the database, rendering, etc?

Comment: Is this in development or production? What queries are you seeing in your log? How are your Hotel, Country, and City associations set up?

Comment: @Sebastien you've definitely got the N+1 problem I suggested. If you make my suggested change, you'll end up with just 3 SQL lines in that file

Comment: I use development environment.

Comment: @Sebastien, I'd suggest you look at the network time too. It looks like this is not running on your local machine. 3 seconds would include the latency, plus the response time, plus the transfer time. How big in kb is the json returned?

Comment: @Matthew Rudy You right but i still has too long requests...

Comment: @Sebastien how big is the json response, firefox should tell you that in the network view.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4222/discussion-between-matthew-rudy-and-sebastien)

Comment: @Matthew Rudy You right, i use a virtual machine with VMware but i tried to deploy my apps on my dedicated server... same performances...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was using VMWare to make my web server running. My performances problems was about that. I find my solution here :

[Webrick is very slow to respond. How to speed it up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156759/webrick-very-slow-when-accessing-applications-from-remote-desktop)

Answer (score 7):

Looking at you code, my guess is you have a simple "N+1" problem.

Namely you load `@hotels` into an array, but when you come to produce the json
you load the `country` and city`for each`hotel.

So for your 40 hotels, you have to do a total of 81 database queries.

This can simply be improved by doing an `include` when you load.

In the old style

```
Hotel.all(:include => [:country, :city])
```

In Rails 3 style

```
Hotel.includes(:country, :city).all
```

With this change you should only be making 3 database calls in total.

See the Rails Guide on [Eager Loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) for more info.

Comment: I try that but it doesn't change my request time.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Log, Rails seems to be thinking it got the response out in 405 ms. This leaves rest of the stack to consider:

1. Rails (✓)
2. Passenger
3. Apache
4. Network
5. DNS resolving
6. Browser rendering

First, see how other browsers fare. I have seen occasional issues on one of our (non-rails) sites with Firefox, while Webkit-based browsers (Safari, Chrome) are OK. Maybe Firefox chokes up for some reason (e.g. [DNS resolving issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428278/site-incredibly-slow-for-firefox-instant-on-every-other-browser-keepalive-issue) or something other).

If all browsers are the same (or especially, if Firefox is the culprit), then open Firebug and take look at the `Net` tab, especially the XHR (AJAX) tab under that. Hover your mouse over one of the queries' time bar to see breakdown of where the time went: DNS, Connecting, Sending, Waiting, Receiving.

If Firebug indicates that the time is spent on the request itself (Sending, Waiting, Receiving), then take a look at Apache log - turn on `CustomLog` time reporting (add `%D` - [see documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html)) and see how long Apache thinks these requests take.

This should narrow down your problem to further analyze causes.